# How to use component which contains actions? Getting error "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to get my component to have some prop actions to do stuff with it (such as user login through a popup eventually):

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Props
{
    dostuff()
    {

    }
}

export class Test extends Component<Props, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (<div>lol</div>);
    }
}
```

In my layouts.tsx I try to do this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';
import { Test } from '../test/test'
import { Component } from 'react';

export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    <Test />
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

However looks like react doesn't like my action in the props..

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Layout.tsx:16:21 
>       TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> &
>   Read...'.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>       Property 'dostuff' is missing in type '{}'.

My props are usually just strings or booleans which I nclude without issue, how do I make it work with functions? If this isn't possible can I put it elsewhere in the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that React very much likes your action in the props, but you're not providing one at `<Test/>`. If you add a method `dostuff` to `Layout` and use `<Test dostuff={this.dostuff}/>`, it should work. Also, you probably want to declare an interface `Props`, instead of a class, as you just want to declare the types there.

Comment: Yeah looks like I don't quite understand how React works exactly. Need to look into exposing actions to components without using props. This got me because I've been going off the visual studio template to teach myself...

Comment: @Obiosys What if `NavMenu` using HIgher-order component inside, which is injecting props? While the `NavMenu` does not have any props passed as attribute? I am getting same error as original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721915/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-dropdownprops-props