# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DropdownProps & Props &

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am using React on Rails | Webpackaer | typescript: "^2.8.1".

I have a High-Order Component, which takes a components and injects few props in it, and return it:

```
export type HCProps = {
  isValid: boolean,
};
```

Then I have a component, which gets injected props from a High-Order Component:

```
import injector, { HCProps } from './HCComponent';
type Props = {};

const LocalComponent: React.SFC<Props & HCProps> = ({ isValid }) => (

);

export default injector(LocalComponent);
```

Here LocalComponent does not take any props like DOM attributes while rendering it as component, but the props are injected by the `HCComponent`:

```
<LocalComponent />
```

This gives me error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HCProps & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'HCProps'.
Property 'isValid' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Any idea why this is happening? I am new to typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are making a mistake when saying

> LocalComponent does not accepts any props while rendering it

Probably, you are rendering the default exported component `injector(LocalComponent)`

In that case, you are using a component whatever injector gave you. There should be a generic type in injector which you should use something like

```
injector<HCProps>(LocalComponent)
```

Comment: Hi, I meant I am just rendering it like `<LocalComponent  />` not like `<LocalComponent isValid={ true } />`. All the props are getting injected through Higher Order component.

Comment: Somehow, the error got removed after I commented `"types": ["node"]` in `compilerOptions`, in `tsconfig.json`. Need to confirm this and read about this config option.

Comment: that's really strange :)
if problem occurs can you create an example repo

Comment: Yeah I'll do that. Thanks.